# Web API Hosting issue

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created an web api application with .net 5 and trying to publish on my machine. I can not access my application after publishing. It shows me Internal server error with error code 0x8007000d. By googling I found this is URL-Rewrite issue. Then I install url-rewrite. But it still not working.
Here is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication5.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: c1a20709-d2a2-4f99-a917-c45766f4e9aa-->
```

Please help me

Comment: Open the event viewer on your system and then check errors under Application category.

Comment: Where i found event viewer? I am new to publishing and hosting

Comment: I assume you are using Windows operating system. So you can follow this guide:
https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/6-ways-to-open-event-viewer-in-windows-10.html

Comment: got it. but what should i do now or what do to, i dont know. I see the event viewer for the first time

Comment: Could you please enable logging.

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to host the asp.net core 5 application on IIS, I suggest you could firstly check you have installed the .net core hosting module. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: after i reinstall hosting module it works fine